# How can I create multiple setInterval()s dynamically?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, setinterval

I have a script that needs a function to be run multiple times per object, but the number of objects is set in a variable by the user.

It would work like this

```
dothis(1);
dothis(2);
dothis(3);
```

However this doesn't work

```
for (var i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
{
    setInterval(
        function()
        {
            dothis(i);
        },
        (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1)
    );
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work why ? please post a log or error output

Comment: If all you want to do is: `dothis(1); dothis(2); ...` Why is `setInterval()` *with a loop* needed? Why would just a loop or just a interval not work?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek each interval should run and finish at different (random) times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to snapshot the value of `i` in a local scope otherwise it gets dynamically 'regenerated' at execution time, which means the value would then always be `howMany`, since the CPU lock, created by the main function, prevents your `setInterval`/`setTimeout` functions to execute before the loop is ended.

```
for (var i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
{
    setInterval(
        function(j)
        {
            return function() { dothis(j); };
        }(i),
        (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1)
    );
}
```

See [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1291428) for further reference.

Comment: thanks. so I guess that would be the same as declaring another function that takes a value and then calls `dothis()` with said value, and then calling `newfunction(i)` which would in turn call `dothis()` with the value of `i`?

Comment: No, because the scope of `i` would still be 1 level above `newfunction` (thus still being dynamically evaluated). The point of using the `j` parameter in my example is to make it *local* hence completely static.